# Passing Id and User Selected Value to the JavaScript from Model List

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

In my web application, there is a section where I load the values from the model using `For` loop

So I added a button to trigger the script.

I want to know how to get the model data `EmpMarks` to the array and sum.

This is the View

```
 <tbody> @for (int i = 0; i < Model.First().KPIMarksVMList.Count(); i++) 
{ 
<tr>
     <td style="display:none;"> @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].KPIId) </td>
     <td width="60%"> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].KPIName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) </td>
     <td>
       <div class="radio"> 
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "1") 1 
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "2") 2 
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "3") 3 
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "4") 4
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.First().KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "5", new { @checked = "Checked" }) 5 </div>
     </td>
     </tr> 
} 
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="Check MarksRequest" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Calculation();" />
```

This is what I tried

```
function Calculation()
{
        var myArray = [];
        @foreach (var item in Model.First().KPIMarksVMList)
        {
             @:myArray.push('@item.EmpMarks');
        }
        console.log(myArray)

}
```

Array Returns with 0. Not getting user clicked value

This is the calculation I want to do in the script.

Need to predefine these in the script.

```
const int kpMarks = 65;
int kpiCounts = mainDetailsVM.KPIMarksVMList.Count();
decimal KpMarksPerQuiz = (kpMarks / kpiCounts) / 5;
decimal kpiMarks = 0;
```

This need to add within the `Foreach`

```
decimal k = KpMarksPerQuiz * item.EmpMarks;
kpiMarks += k;
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to just calculaten them on the server and pass them to the model there?

Comment: @Marco I tried passing the model using Ajax call to the controller. But the thing is when it passes to the model. It does not collect the user-selected values from the radio buttons to the controller. Only model is passing.

Comment: No, on your Get request in your controller action method, create an array with all empMarks, since you already know them. There is no need to calculate them on the client or go back to calculate them.

Comment: @Marco Great Idea. ! Thanks. But the issue is the way my code doesn't pass the values to the array. ``@:myArray.push('@item.EmpMarks');`` This line. I think some lines missing, need to get the selected value from the ``<div class="radio"> `` but I don't know how to do it. :|

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass the values from View to Controller by changing `.First()` in the View to `[0]`, e.g. `@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model[0].KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "1")`

The name attribute generated in the View is different for `.First()` and `[0]`.
When using `.First()`:

```
<input id="KPIMarksVMList_0__EmpMarks" name="KPIMarksVMList[0].EmpMarks" type="radio" value="1" />
```

When using `[0]`:

```
<input name="[0].KPIMarksVMList[0].EmpMarks" type="radio" value="1">
```

Changing `.First()` to `[0]` allow Razor to generate correct HTML to pass data from View to Controller.
Here are the code for ajax call:

```
@model List<MyModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Calculation", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form" }))
{
    ...
    <div class="radio">
        <div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model[0].KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "1") 1</div>
        <div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model[0].KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "2") 2</div>
        <div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model[0].KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "3") 3</div>
        <div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model[0].KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "4") 4</div>
        <div>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model[0].KPIMarksVMList[i].EmpMarks, "5", new { @checked = "Checked" }) 5</div>
    </div>
    ...
<input type="button" value="Check MarksRequest" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submitForm()"/>
}
```

```
<script>
    function submitForm(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Controller/Calculation',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

```
public JsonResult Calculation(List<MyModel> dataList)
{
    const int kpMarks = 65;
    int kpiCounts = dataList.First().KPIMarksVMList.Count();
    decimal KpMarksPerQuiz = (kpMarks / kpiCounts) / 5;
    decimal kpiMarks = 0;

    foreach (var item in dataList.First().KPIMarksVMList)
    {
        decimal k = KpMarksPerQuiz * item.EmpMarks;
        kpiMarks += k;
    }

    return Json(new { kpiMarks = kpiMarks });
}
```

Comment: Really Appreciate your effort. I want to try this , but I want to know that in the view I used ``for`` loop to load the radio buttons for the 1 Id. So how to use it in your way

Comment: @DevBeginner Sorry I skip that part by '...' actually I didn't change other lines in the view except those with `@Html.RadioButtonFor`